# Converting dice faces into one another in Anydice

Tags: anydice

**System**

In this system, we'll be rolling only two custom d6s to determine the outcomes. Each d6 can show 3 types of symbols that we are calling A (bad outcome), B (good outcome), and C (null, but can be converted to either) for now. Some faces might have 2 different symbols, like A and C, or also a pair of the same symbols, like 2 Cs.

When you roll the dice, you apply both results. So let's say that I roll an A and a B, what happens is one bad outcome and one good outcome. Two As would give me 2 bad outcomes and so on. If I rolled an A and a C, only a bad outcome would happen, since Cs are worthless unless I have some way to convert it into B (special ability, resource, etc).

**Program**

```
function: convertc C:s LIMIT:n {
  loop I over C {
    if I <= LIMIT {
      C: C - 1
      result: 1
    }
  }
  result: 0
}


function: outcome ROLL:s {
  A: 0
  B: 0
  C: 0

  \ FACES \
  loop I over ROLL {  
    if I = 1 { A: A + 1 }
    if I = 2 { B: B + 1 }
    if I = 3 { C: C + 1 }
    if I = 4 { C: C + 1 }
    if I = 5 { C: C + 1 }
    if I = 6 { 
               A: A + 1
               C: C + 1
             }
  }

  \ Conversion of Cs to Bs to represent bonuses \
  if LIMIT > 0 {
    B: B + [convertc C LIMIT]
  }

 \ Sorting outcomes \
  if C = 0 {
    if B = 0 { result: -100 } \ Only As rolled \
    if A = 0 { result:  100 } \ Only Bs rolled \
    if B >= (A * 2) { result: 100 }
    if A >= (B * 2) { result: -100 }
    if B = A { result: 0 }
  }
  if B > 0 {
    if A = 0 { result: 100 }
    if B >= (A * 2) { result: 100 } 
    }
  if A > 0 {
    if B = 0 { result: -100 }
    if A >= (B * 2) { result: -100 }
    }
  if B = A { result: 0 }

  result: 999 \ Default result \

}

output [outcome 2d6]
```

The [program](https://anydice.com/program/2fd73) primarily keeps track of three variables: A, B, and C.

To emulate cases where the player would have a number of Cs converted into Bs, the program uses a function where Cs are deducted and added to Bs based on a manually specified LIMIT (ie. the maximum amount of conversions possible).

After that, the program applies sorting rules to narrow down the final result into 3 categories: -100 is mostly bad outcomes, 0 is a balance between good and bad, and 100 is mostly good outcomes. I'm narrowing down to those three just to achieve a solid balance before I can start opening up for more granularity.

**Problem**

After a long battle I've managed to make the program work somewhat as intended, but I feel like I reached to my limit (both in programming skills and energy). See, the problem is when I'm inputting a LIMIT of conversions over 2, in that case, the results don't change no matter how I setup the amount each C is worth in the dice symbol distribution. If for example I change

`if I = 3 { C: C + 1 }`
to
`if I = 3 { C: C + 3 }`

The output is the same for LIMIT = 3 than it is for LIMIT = 1. It's like it only converts a C only once, regardless if it is worth 2 or more.

Is it a problem on the function that converts the Cs into Bs? Or is it a logic problem? Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this function:

```
function: convertc C:s LIMIT:n {
  loop I over C {
    if I <= LIMIT {
      C: C - 1
      result: 1
    }
  }
  result: 0
}
```

which you call using

```
B: B + [convertc C LIMIT]
```

You have several issues here.

- When you call `convertc`, you are sending a `n`umber to a parameter of type `s`equence. This means that inside the scope of `convertc`, `C` is a sequence containing one element. Therefore the loop only ever executes once.
- The `C` here is not the same as the `C` in the scope of your `outcome` function, so any changes to `C` inside the scope of `convertc` will not be reflected in the scope of `outcome`. I'm not sure of your intent here.
- Functions return immediately when a value is assigned to `result`, and also you are not accumulating more than one conversion anyways, so only one conversion would ever be done regardless of the value of `LIMIT`.

You can replace the call to `convertc` with

```
CONVERSIONS: [lowest of C and LIMIT]
B: B + CONVERSIONS
C: C - CONVERSIONS
```

Comment: Such a simple but clever solution! I have much to learn, thank you for the insight!